# Como puedo animar una imagen en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imagen, android-imageview

me gustaría animar una imagen en android studio para que parezca que la estoy pulsando, e probado con rescalarla y volverla a poner a su tamaño original pero se hace tan rápido que no te das cuenta de que lo haya hecho

Alguna forma de hacerlos? Estoy usando una versión sdk mínima 15, me gustaría que siguiera así, aunque si hay que cambiarla tampoco habría problema

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static TextView mText, Score;
private static ImageView avatar;
private static double Scor = 0;
private static double dificultadScor = 0;
private static int seconds = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_game);
    mText = findViewById(R.id.mText);
    avatar = findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    Score = findViewById(R.id.score);
    Scor = 0;
    SharedPreferences pr = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String dificultad = pr.getString("dificultad", "1");

    switch(dificultad){

        case "1":
            seconds = 30000;
            dificultadScor = 0.25;
            avatar.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emadera));
            break;

        case "2":
            seconds = 15000;
            dificultadScor = 0.5;
            avatar.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ehierro));
            break;

        case "3":
            seconds = 7000;
            dificultadScor = 0.75;
            avatar.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.eoro));
            break;

        case "4":
            seconds = 3000;
            dificultadScor = 1;
            avatar.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ediamante));
            break;
    }

    countStart();

    avatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Scor += dificultadScor;
            Score.setText("Score: " + Scor);
            avatar.getLayoutParams().height = 119;
            avatar.getLayoutParams().width = 145;
            avatar.getLayoutParams().height = 219;
            avatar.getLayoutParams().width = 245;

        }
    });


}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();




}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this);

    builder.setTitle("Salir de la partida");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent myintent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(myintent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", null);
    builder.create();
    builder.show();

}

public void countStart(){

    new CountDownTimer(seconds, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {//Cuando cambia el contador
            //Actualizamos la etiqueta que muestra el contador
            if(millisUntilFinished<7){
                mText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.alarm));
            }
            mText.setText("Segundos restantes: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);


        }
        //Evento que se lanza cuando acaba la cuenta atrás
        public void onFinish() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this);

            builder.setTitle("Partida Finalizada");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Jugar otra vez", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Scor = 0;
                    countStart();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Salir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myintent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.create();
            builder.show();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

Hay estaría toda la clase, la parte de las imagenes para no buscar tanto es esta

```
switch(dificultad){

        case "1":
            seconds = 30000;
            dificultadScor = 0.25;
            avatar.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emadera));
            break;

        case "2":
            seconds = 15000;
            dificultadScor = 0.5;
            avatar.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ehierro));
            break;

        case "3":
            seconds = 7000;
            dificultadScor = 0.75;
            avatar.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.eoro));
            break;

        case "4":
            seconds = 3000;
            dificultadScor = 1;
            avatar.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ediamante));
            break;
```

Simplemente quiero que al pulsar sobre la imagen parezca que se realiza alguna animación de pulsación, como si la imagen se pusiera más oscura o se contraiga, etcetera etcetera.

Comment: Si compartes lo que has intentado hasta el momento seguro que los usuarios te podran ayudar mejor :)

Comment: Porque no agregas lo que has probado, sería buena idea para saber con más detalle que intentas realizar, revisar [ask], saludos.